# Why is git showing these files as removed and added vs. moved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

So I need to upgrade an rails 2.3.14 app to rails 3. We use git, so decided to create another branch 'rails3' (git checkout -b rails3). The easiest solution I found to the problem of the upgrade was removing all stuff and generating a new project and copy/pasting controllers , views, etc.. from master. But now `git status` tells me those files were deleted and regenerated, not *modified*, although most of them are in the same place they were before. So changes remain obscure, other programmers wont see the subtle changes to files.

What have I've done:

```
/path/to/rails_project/ (master) $ git checkout -b rails3
/path/to/rails_project/ (rails3) $ rm -rf ./* # not git rm
/path/to/ $ rails new rails_project
/path/to/rails_project/ (rails3) $ cp old/project/stuff/from/another/dir
```

How can I 'tell' git that these files were modified, not deleted and regenerated? I have the upgraded app in a totally different directory so its fine to implode cosmos and do all from start.

Comment: This isn't a rails-specific question, so I'd remove the ruby-on-rails tag and remove rails from the question title and instead call it something like "Why is git showing these files as removed and added vs. moved?"

Comment: I used the rails tag because this is also related to how to manage git commits when imploding and regenerating/upgrading a rails app. Maybe someone out there knows a better way to do this specific task. The title makes sense anyway.

Comment: Add the output of `git status` and any applicable recent commits with `git log --stat`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like git is right if what you said below is correct

> "The easiest solution I found to the problem of the upgrade was removing all stuff and generating a new project and copy/pasting controllers , views, etc.. from master."

If the files are as you want them to be, why not just:
git add
git commit

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't automatically delete anything. You must have been using an IDE or editor that was calling `git rm ...` and then `git add ...` and you just didn't see it.

To avoid this, use git at command line or with a tool that is more obvious. And instead of `git rm` and `git add` for something that is the same file, use `git mv`. Sometimes git figures out moves on its own when you rm and add, but with mv it doesn't have to guess.

Comment: I wasn't using any IDE. I just ran `rm -rf ./*`. Still git detects the missing files as deleted. When I generate the new project and paste the old stuff git status throws "deleted: /path/to/file1" and "new file: /path/to/file1"

Comment: Ah, ok. If the path is moving, do `git mv old_pathname new_pathname` and replace the moved file with the newer version before `git add`. But if you only `rm` (not `git rm`) and then replace the file, git should not recognize the file as deleted if the file name and path is same and you've done no git operations to the file. Note though that many of us are ok with some stuff looking like files are recreated when they aren't since git sometimes gets it wrong. Sometimes a little forgiveness is ok, right? :)